# Change array element name without flattening with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have the following code:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Database")]
public class SqlDatabase
{
    public List<SqlTable> Tables { get; private set; }
}
```

If I use `XmlSerializer` without any custom attribute, generated XML persists list hierarchy:

```
<Database>
  <Tables>
    <SqlTable Name="Table1" />
    <SqlTable Name="Table2" />
  </Tables>
</Database>
```

However, **I want to change the element name "SqlTable" to "Table".** I tried to use `XmlElement` attribute on the list

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Database")]
public class SqlDatabase
{
    [XmlElement("Table")]
    public List<SqlTable> Tables { get; private set; }
}
```

The name is changed but the hierarchy is flattened:

```
<Database>
  <Table Name="Table1" />
  <Table Name="Table2" />
</Database>
```

Then I tried `XmlArray` attribute, which changes the name of the list but not the elements within:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Database")]
public class SqlDatabase
{
    [XmlArray("Foo")]
    public List<SqlTable> Tables { get; private set; }
}
```

Results in

```
<Database>
  <Foo>
    <SqlTable Name="Table1" />
    <SqlTable Name="Table2" />
  </Foo>
</Database>
```

I tried to combine these two and there is an exception saying they can't be used together.

So the question is, **is there a simple way to change the element name without flattening the hierarchy?**

Comment: I think this answer will solve your problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6462300/1181408

Comment: yes, use a combination of XmlArray and XmlArrayItem attributes as @cgotberg suggests

Comment: @cgotberg Thanks, it is the answer I am looking for. Didn't see it because the title of that question seemed irrelevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use XmlElementAttribute for List<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462091/how-to-use-xmlelementattribute-for-listt)